# Is it possible to get current time from cellular network in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, core-telephony

Is it possible to get current time through cellular network or using CoreTelephony
in iOS. I am doing some activity with current time. But when user changes time through settings it will affect. If it is online mode then it will ok. But I need current time in offline mode.

Comment: No Apple has not API available that will allow this.

Comment: Is there any possibilities to get current time independent of Device Time in iOS ?

Comment: You can use any NTP server, but you will have to be online. Like many time based games you wil have to online to play to the game.

Comment: There appears to be several NTP client implementations in Objective-C. A quick Google for "NTP client Objective-C" should turn up several options.

Comment: @KK M， why you do not use `NSDate`?

Comment: @aircraft Because I need exact time if there is a situation for Time In and Time Out for any business. Then there is a chance the worker will cheat by changing the time. And more I am always saving data in local in offline mode. And when I get in online I am updating to Server. I hope you got my point.

Comment: `NSDate` is a date in machine time, not in user time. You can use `NSDate` out of the box for this with no issues — it carries no information about localization, current user time, etc. Only when you go to format it/use it with an `NSCalendar` does that come into play. Just capture `NSDate`s and compare them if need be.